# TabHost при использовании setIndicator(view) пропадает индикация выбора

Tags: android, вкладки

В TabHost при использовании setIndicator(String, Drawable) все как и ожидалось *выбран второй элемент он и подсвечен*
[image: setIndicator(String, Drawable) выбран второй элемент] ,

 но при setIndicator(View)  подставляется заранее созданный view но нет индикации выбора ( *выбран первый элемент* ).[image: setIndicator(View) выбран первый элемент]

Подскажите как исправить ситуацию и как взамен подсвечивания подставлять свое изображение (таб не выбран - одно изображение, таб выбран - другое)

Answer (score 1):

Сперва делаешь selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--  Active tab -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected" />
    <!--  Inactive tab -->
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected" />
    <!--  Pressed tab -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <!--  Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

tab_bg_selected.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#A8A8A8" android:centerColor="#7F7F7F"
        android:endColor="#696969" android:angle="-90" />
</shape>
```

tab_bg_unselected.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#5C5C5C" android:centerColor="#424242"
        android:endColor="#222222" android:angle="-90" />
</shape>
```

Затем в коде:

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);
```

А по первому вопросу, видимо у тебя TabHost использован с viewpager например, тогда достаточно переключить страницу в viewPager и тогда tabhos измениться на слеедующий.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, вроде разобрался как использовать селектор, только не понял, можно ли менять не фон, а именно изображение.

Comment: @x555xx если ответ помог, прошу отметить сообщение как решение, согласно правилам stackOverFlow.